# MySQL: Get the first row that has a field >= value - is there a way to speed it up?

Tags: mysql, optimization, where-clause

There is a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `thing` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`thing`,`price`),
  KEY `thing` (`thing`),
  KEY `price` (`price`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and some values there:

```
INSERT INTO test(thing,price)
VALUES
(1,5.00),
(2,7.50),
(3,8.70),
(4,9.00),
(5,9.50),
(6,9.75),
(7,10.00),
(8,10.50),
(9,10.75),
(10,11.00),
(11,11.25);
```

I want to get a MINIMAL `price` from this table, that is MORE than, say, `9.2` - that is `(5,9.50)` record. So, I do:
`SELECT thing, price FROM test WHERE price > 9.2 ORDER BY price LIMIT 1` . It's EXPLAIN output says that MySQL goes through all 7 rows that are more than 9.2:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  test    range   price   price   5   \N  7   Using where; Using index
```

Is there a way to speed this up somehow? So that MySQL would give me ONE record that is a little more than my condition?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Heh, StackOverflow gets rid of my "Hello everyone!" :(

Comment: No Way. I think there's NO WAY since you're issuing an `ORDER BY` there and so MySQL has to go through those 7 rows that have Price > 9.2.

Comment: @LenielMacaferi: Please read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) -- although not directly applicable, it should give an idea of what a way could be.

Comment: Logically there is no way to get the minimum value without going through all of those 7 records unless the values are pre-sorted.

Answer (score 0):

How fast do you want it to be? How slow is this now? This could be a case of pre-mature optimization. Please understand that the number of rows in the explain plan is just an estimate.

But none the less, try this if it makes any difference (??):

```
SELECT thing, min(price) FROM test WHERE price > 9.2
```

Comment: @Jon Yes but as I understand it, if there is no `group by` clause then it applies to all rows. In this case, it is for those records `WHERE price > 9.2` and based on OP's post of `give me ONE record that is a little more than my condition`, `min()` will give the least price above 9.2

Answer (score 0):

Create an index on `price`. You probably don't want to have the primary key on `(thing, price)`, because that would allow a `thing` to have more than one `price`. Just make `thing` the primary key. (I am assuming that you don't want a particular `thing` to have multiple `price` values.)